# Knockout JS - Hyperlink not handled in Selenium webdriver

Tags: knockout.js, selenium-webdriver, knockout-mvc

unable to click the Hyperlink using Selenium wbedriver, because they (Developers) used Knockout JS with MVC, so please give an steps how to handle in Automate for these type of JS

for example

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.lnkAdd">New Grade</a>
```

during the testing i want to click that hyperlink (New Grade)

so please help me out how to do this

regards
prabu

Comment: What do you mean on "not handled"? How is your automation code looks like? Are you waiting for the page load and the databidning finishes before you try to click?

Answer (score 2):

3 ways to do that.

Normal way

```
WebElement link=browser.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='New Grade']"));
link.click();
//click once again
link.click();
```

Keyboard way, ENTER key

```
link.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

nasty tricky way, move to that link and then click or send ENTER key

```
Actions moveTo = new Actions(driver);
moveTo.moveToElement(link).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Saved my life 5 years later. How did you figure out that the Knockout element needed to be clicked twice?

Comment: @DavidHyogo Sorry for late response. As far as I remember, the 1st click was more like a "focus" on the link, then the 2nd click was the "real action".

Answer (score 1):

Using Knockout doesn't change the way you locate elements on the page. It's still just regular html at the end of the day.
My selenium experience is a bit dated, but I used to always target elements using xpath

ex: `sel.Click("//a[text()='New Grade']")`